# Laravel 5.5 select users based on session with roles as

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to select all users of sessions where roles for the users are not admin or only roles where roles.name is user.

my user table is

[image]

session table is
[image]

and roles table is this

[image]

I am running this query and it is working fine but it selects all users including admin user. I only want to select user where roles.name is user

```
    $sessions = Sessions::where('user_id', '<>', 'NULL')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', 'sessions.user_id')
                        ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name',
                            DB::raw('count(sessions.user_id) as counts'))
                        ->get();
```

Comment: try using eloquent relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I think you need to add a role_id column to the users table.

Comment: I was thinking about that but why my admin and user login working fine.when I use admin credentials on login it redirects me to admin dashboard and when i use user credentials then it redirects me to user dashboard . I dont know how it is all working.

Answer (score 0):

You have first to join the roles with the users table, since there is no way with the set up you gave to know what is the role of a certain user, so after adding `role_id` as a foreign key in the users table you can make your query like this:

```
$sessions = Sessions::where('user_id', '<>', 'NULL')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', 'sessions.user_id') 
                        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', 'users.role_id')   
                        ->where('roles.name','user')
                        ->select('roles.name as role','users.first_name','users.last_name',
                            DB::raw('count(sessions.user_id) as counts'))
                        ->get();
```

Comment: there is no role_id in my user table

Comment: it's mendatory, because otherwise how does it work in login? do you have another table called user_role or something?

Comment: No I dont have that, I other table model_has_role in user models are defined I think it is getting roles according to models for user and for admin seperately

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB query for this..

```
DB::table(sessions)->where('roles', $user->hasRole('user'))->get();
```

:)